# jQuery activate single tab with multiple links - setting active class on both at same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

as the title says, I want to make a tab interface where I have multiple links that control the same tab panel.

Hopefully you'll get what I mean when you look at the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kimatg/EtVZW/2/

Here everything works just fine and the links all work well, but one problem is that the "active" class (in this case `.current`) will only work in one tab-selector-containers at a time...

In other words, I have 2 tab menus (`.map` and `.tabnav`) in the demo; when I click *Region 2* in `div.tabnav`, the corresponding `a` tag gets class `.current`, but the corresponding `a` tag in `div.map` doesn't.

How can I make both divs get `.current` classes at the same time and not when another tab is selected?

Oh and by the way I used jQuery Tools in the example, but It's fine if there's a need to implement it a different way like jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with jQuery Tools so I used UI.

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/XwpDK/4/

Basically, I used the index to highlight the proper link

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
    select : function(event, ui) {
        var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); 
        $('a').removeClass('highlight');
        $('a').eq(ui.index).addClass('highlight');
    }
});

$('.map a:first').addClass('highlight');
$('.map a').click(function(){
    $tabs.tabs( "select" , $(this).index());
});
```

Comment: Hmm, strange, while the top links work, I can't navigate with the bottom links (tabs) at all. 

Oh and the first tab should be always selected by default, in both navigations as well. Any way to implement this?

Comment: Whoops, sorry that's my fault. I made a small change without testing. Updated the reply to this effect :)

Comment: sorry for an extremely late reply, your example worked perfectly, it was just what I needed. Thanks much! :D